# Executing an SQL update query from a sub form sourcing a control on a main

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In the code below I am trying to retrieve the value located in the control box 'cbodepartments' which sits on the main form 'frmstaticdatadepartments07'.  I am trying to take that value and insert it into table 'tblvaluechain01' for in every record where the value in the field 'team' is equal to zero.

The error message i am currently getting is: that the query does not recognise the string i am using to source the control: [Forms]![frmstaticdatadepartments07]![cbodepartments]

```
sql_get = "UPDATE tblvaluechain01 SET notes = [Forms]![frmstaticdatadepartments07]![cbodepartments] WHERE [tblvaluechain01].[team]=0"
```

Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (sql_get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to concatenate the String you are passing to the Query. Try this,

```
sql_get = "UPDATE tblvaluechain01 SET notes = " & Chr(34) & _
          [Forms]![frmstaticdatadepartments07]![cbodepartments] & Chr(34) & _
          " WHERE [tblvaluechain01].[team] = 0"
```

Comment: Hello PaulFrancis. Sorry what does the Chr(34) represent?

Comment: Chr(34) returns the character for the ASCII equivalent of 34, which is " which needs to be in place for strings.